# Running Rails Server on Cloud9 results in 'Server timed out or sent incomplete response'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, cloud9-ide

I've been following the railstutorial.org and have everything has been running fine, but now when I run `rails server -b $IP -p $PORT`, the rails server seems to take forever to respond, causing the cloud9 proxy to time out and send this message:

*Something went wrong !*

*Server timed out or sent incomplete response*

*Click here to try again, or Go back to dashboard.*
*If that still doesn't work, please Issue a bug report.*

Any idea how I can work around this/resolve it to get a working production preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that you wrote:

```
rails server -b -$IP ...
```

There shouldn't be a - before `$IP`. Can you see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: Hi, this is my mistake. I've updated the post with what I actually use. The `rails server` command works fine, but the preview never loads—just times out!

Comment: Can you try again after restarting your workspace? you can do that by clicking on the stats menu item near the top right, and click on 'Restart'

Comment: Hurray! That worked. So simple! I thought that the workspace restarted after exit, but this solved it. Thanks so much!